# Scala Eclipse file>new has <No Applicable Items>

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I downloaded the Scala IDE for Mac 64 bit from http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html

I open the program, click File > New and see .

The Coursera tutorial I'm in says that I should see the option to create a new Scala project. It looks like I have the IDE but not the SDK?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest reason to get this behavior would be if all perspectives are closed.

Most of the menus in Eclipse are contextual, and `File > New` is empty if there is no current perspective.

To open a perspective, use `Windows > Open Perspective > Other...`, then select `Scala` and `OK`. Then `File > New` contains the list of the Scala related wizard.

Comment: Also, Scala IDE does contain the full SDK, and the bundle is an all-in-one download with everything needed to have a running Scala IDE.

Comment: The first time I installed it it didn't come with it.

Comment: This issue also occurs when you've opened the wrong perspective. When the _Debug_ perspective is open there are no entries in the "New" menu. When the _Java_ perspective is open all entries are present.