# Scale IDE error when I try to make a new scala project

Tags: eclipse, scala

I installed Scala IDE 4.7.0 and tried to make a new scala project.

But there was "No Applicable Items". (File > New > No Applicable Items)

So, I opened the opening wizard by cmd+N, and chose the scala project.

And, Here is the error code:

Problem Opening Wizard

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.scala-ide.sdt.core was unable to load class org.scalaide.ui.internal.wizards.ScalaProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.scala-ide.sdt.core (333).

I did almost everything, e.g. reinstall, remove workspace directory, etc.
But nothing helped out.

Appreciate if someone fix this!

Comment: did you try invalidate cache and restart? and your problem is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309723/scala-eclipse-filenew-has-no-applicable-items

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I already saw that post and but didn't help. And I did what you told me to do (eclipse -clean), but this didn't help, either.

Comment: I have the same problem! Both with Scala IDE 4.7.0 and 4.7.1 RC3. I have the feeling it could be related with the Eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=520176 that disables all menus on Mac OS High Sierra but the workaround described there does not work. Latest Eclipse release itself, however, does work. Please help! It‘s a pity that I can’t use the latest Scala IDE since in the older version the Scala Test recognizer is totally broken.